# Is this understandable? - "they claimed that seeing what"

Tags: sentence-construction

> Pay attention who said that you were chatty, **they claimed that seeing what**?

I mean on what basis specific people think that somebody is talkative, what they saw and in which situations that they claim what they claim.

"they claimed that seeing what?" - Is it a good sequence? Should I write it in some other way?

*they claimed that - here I mean "claimed so", "claimed in that way"

Comment: The whole sentence is unidiomatic. Who is being asked to pay attention? You can't use 'who said' without referring to a subject - 'The people who said...'

Comment: I ask certain person and that person has to answer me who claimed that the person is chatty

Comment: At the moment, this question is off-topic for this site. You can't just ask "is this correct" or "find the error". If you think it is correct while someone else says it is wrong, tell us why you think it is correct. Or if you have a reason for confusion as to why it isn't right, explain that in your answer.

Comment: If 'Pay attention' is just something you are using to attract the listener's attention, you could put an exclamation mark after it, and you certainly need to start a new sentence for the actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example sentence:

> Pay attention who said that you were chatty, they claimed that seeing what?

is not correct English. Until I read the explanation in the question, I had no idea what it was intended to mean. It could be rewritten as:

> Pay attention **to** who said that you were being chatty, and to what they said that they were seeing.

"Pay attention to" is a verbal phrase, the "to" is needed to indicate what is to be attended to. what the people said is a second thing that then listener is to pay attention to. "what they said"  (or "what they claimed") becomes a second object of the verb "pay attention". I changed "claimed" to "said" because it is less confrontational. To call something a claim is to imply that you think it isn't true, or at least doubt it. "said" is more neutral. Of course, in some cases the speaker intends to be confrontational. This sentence isn't a question, it ius an instruction, so I removed the question mark.

More formally one could say "Pay attention to who it was that said that you were chatty" This more clearly asks the listener to identify those people, but this form is a little unlikely in casual speech.

If the intent was to have an instruction followed by a question, this should be split into two sentences. For example:

> Pay attention **to** who said that you were being chatty. What did they claim that they were seeing?

But this is a little awkward. The instruction is for future action, the listener is to pay attention on a future occasion. But the question is about what has already been said. Such mixtures do happen in speech, but they can confuse the hearers.